# Add a rule for `:checked` in a jquery object variable

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

```js
let input = $('div').find('input');

$('button').on('click', () => {
    if (input.is(':checked')){
    $('p').html(input.val());
  }
  else {
    $('p').html("No value provided");
  }
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio-div">
  <input type="radio" id="y" name="yorn" value="Yes">
  <label for="y">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="n" name="yorn" value="No">
  <label for="n">No</label><br>
  <button>Check Value</button>
  <p>

  </p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the values of all the inputs in my form one by one. But I cannot get the radiobuttons values, they always return the same value:

But it checkes if any of the choices of input is checked and always returns the first option (even if "No" is checked, the `input.val()` is "Yes"). How to make it work assuming I want to use `let input` variable as above not just `$('input:checked')` selector?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Malvinka87/0qdj6bLw/8/

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Malvinka87/0qdj6bLw/8/

Comment: What's a "rulse"? Also, please include all code necessary to reproduce the issue in the question, not just on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in a page on the editor toolbar) to provide an interface much like jsFiddle.

Comment: "Rulse" obviously is just a typo in word "rule".

Comment: Stack Snippet added.

Comment: `input` is a jQuery object with two elements in it. Using `.is(":checked")` will always return true, since at least one of the radio buttons is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem: the solution is to use `filter` method like this:

```
if (input.is(':checked')){
    $('p').html(input.filter(':checked').val());
  }
```